# Show the border of a layout column on a wikipage

Tags: sharepoint-online

I have a wiki-library which contains wiki-pages. I put a layout "Column with side bar on every wiki page.
So i have 1 big column and a small one which will be displayed when the page is in edit-mode. How can i show the border of the big column?

Greetings, P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What did you mean "show the border of the big column"?

Per my test, it's by default that the black border of the big column will appear when selecting it, show as below:

[image]

Comment: Yes you have the page in edit-mode. But the border of the column will dissapear when the page is not in editmode. Is it possible to show the border when the page is not in editmode. Gr. P